# Download files asynchrounsly and parse them synchronously with Node JS

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise, gulp

I have a gulp task that downloads a few JSON files from GitHub, then prompts the user for values to replace in those files. For example, I have an `.ftpconfig` that gets download, and then the user is asked to enter hostname, username, password, and path.

Because the file first needs to be downloaded before it can be configured, and each file needs to be configured sequentially, I'm using quite a few nested callbacks. I'd like to change this "callback hell" system so that it utilizes async/await and/or promises instead, but I'm having a lot of difficulty understanding exactly why my code isn't working; it seems that promises fire their `.then()` functions asynchronously, which doesn't make sense to me.

My goals are as follows:

1. Download all config files asynchronously
2. Wait for all config files to finish downloading
3. Read existing settings from the config files
4. Prompt the user for changed settings in each config file synchronously

I've tried a number of approaches, none of which worked. I discarded the code I've used, but here's a rough recreation of the things I've tried:

Attempt #1:

```
return new Promise((resolve) => {
    // download files...
}).then((resolve) => {
    // configure first file...
}).then((resolve) => {
    // configure second file...
}).then((resolve) => {
    // configure thrid file...
});
```

Attempt #2:

```
const CONFIG_FILES = async () => {
    const bs_download    = await generate_config("browsersync");
    const ftp_download   = await generate_config("ftp");
    const rsync_download = await generate_config("rsync");

    return new Promise(() => {
        configure_json("browsersync");
    }).then(() => {
        configure_json("ftp");
    }).then(() => {
        configure_json("rsync");
    });
};
```

I'm sure I'm doing something very obviously wrong, but I'm not adapt enough at JavaScript to see the problem. Any help would be great appreciated.

My gulp task can be found here:

- [gulpfile.js](https://github.com/JacobDB/new-site/blob/4f95efa7a52f166656a8fc92464eecd79b878430/gulpfile.js)
- [gulp-tasks/config.js](https://github.com/JacobDB/new-site/blob/4f95efa7a52f166656a8fc92464eecd79b878430/gulp-tasks/config.js)

Comment: a promise will run sequentially if the async tasks within them resolve the promise asynchronously. Attempt #1 would only work if you were returning a promise from the .then. Attempt #2 won't work because you never resolved the first promise, and then you aren't returning a promise from any of the .thens. You can't make asynchronous code run synchronously, but you can make it run sequentially by using promises. async/await makes it look synchronous, but under the covers it's still a promise chain, so you should get it to work with promises first because that's a prerequisite of async/await.

Comment: Promises don't just magically make async tasks run sequentially or synchronously. If the async tasks return a promise, they can be used in a .then chain to make them run sequentially, else you'll have to wrap it in a promise or another function that returns a promise to have the same effect without "callback hell".

Comment: Thanks, I think that helps me understand a bit what's happening. I'll make another attempt and report back.

Comment: @KevinB thanks for that! I was able to get it working mostly how I wanted it to, and I think I see how I can finish it up for the most part. https://github.com/JacobDB/new-site/blob/d119b8b3c22aa7855791ab6b0ff3c2e33988b4b2/gulp-tasks/config.js

Comment: The main suggestion i'll make on that code is make sure you reject when there's an error too, you don't want to have lingering unresolved promises.

Comment: [line 234](https://github.com/JacobDB/new-site/blob/d119b8b3c22aa7855791ab6b0ff3c2e33988b4b2/gulp-tasks/config.js#L234) can be shortened to `return configure_json(".rsyncconfig", "rsync", prompts)`. No need to create a promise around something that already returns one (repeated a few other times throughout the code)

Comment: Thanks, I'll take care of that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @EricB, I was able to figure out what I was doing wrong. It was mostly a matter of making my functions return promises as well.

https://github.com/JacobDB/new-site/blob/d119b8b3c22aa7855791ab6b0ff3c2e33988b4b2/gulp-tasks/config.js